# How can I atomically swap two pointers on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows

Okay, I'm asking the same thing as [this deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4502523/how-can-i-implement-an-atomic-swap-for-a-stdauto-ptr-lookalike), but I'm asking it more directly.

I've got two pointer variables in two instances of the same class. I'd like to swap the contents of those variables (not what they POINT to, just the variables themselves) atomically.

I'd like to avoid locks if at all possible.

How do I do this?

**EDIT:** To the three zillion "InterlockedExchangePointer" answers, please read the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683609.aspx) first. InterlockedExchangePointer exchanges the value of a pointer target with a <s>value on the stack</s> register. It (by itself) does not exchange two pointers in memory locations.

Comment: I don't think there is a non-locking X86 instruction to swap the contents of two memory addresses.  Without CPU support it would be difficult to implement such a function.  Are there any guarantees about the pointers?  (e.g., are they always adjacent in memory?  If so, you could use an 8-byte or 16-byte compare/exchange in a loop.)

Comment: @James:  Since you posted the same thing on everyone's comment:  `int* p1 = somevalue; int* p2 = someothervalue; p2 = InterlockedExchangePointer(p1, p2);` would do just that.  Though, underneath it uses a critical section, so I'm not sure it quite matches with the need to avoid locks completely.

Comment: wow, a lot of people giving the wrong answer... this should be an interview question `:-)`

Comment: And who the heck starts upvoting the wrong answers?

Comment: @Zac:  No, it won't.  `InterlockedExchangePointer` takes the address of a pointer and the pointer to store at that address.  It would take two calls to `InterlockedExchangePointer` to swap the values of two pointers and while each call to an `Interlocked` function is atomic, two calls are not together atomic.

Comment: @Billy: "... with a value on the stack." There is absolutely no mention of the stack anywhere in the docs. Where did you pull that from? Did *you* read the docs?

Comment: @James:  I stand corrected.  I was reading the documentation to mean you could use the return value to do the swap without thinking the copy-assignment for the second pointer wouldn't be interlocked.

Comment: @Zac, @gimpf:  And its thread-unsafe.

Comment: @OJ: It's a function parameter, ergo, it's going onto the stack. @James' point is that inside the function it comes off the stack, which is probably true.

Comment: @Billy:  Yeah.  Technically the pointer value could be anywhere the compiler wants to put it.  On X86, I'm almost positive that has to be in a register.  I'm not an X86 expert though, hence why I've only been pestering people via comments instead of answering the question :-)

Comment: @James: Yes, the instruction only works with a memory location and two registers.

Comment: I don't understand... Are these pointers both read in one atomic read? If not it shouldn't matter whether your swap is atomic or not.

Comment: @Chris:  As stated, he is asking for an atomic, lock-free implementation of `swap(void*&, void*&)`.

Comment: @Chris: He has two pointers. He wants to read from pointer 1, read from pointer 2, write the value at pointer 2 to pointer 1, and write the value at pointer 1 to pointer 2. All atomically.

Comment: @james, @wj32: I know what he wants. My point was that without the ability to read them both atomically, there is no need to swap them both atomically, as the possible execution paths are basically the same whether or not you use atomic swap.

Comment: @Chris: That doesn't make any sense. Consider two threads swapping with the same value. Thread 1 reads the value, thread 2 reads the value, thread 2 writes it's new value, thread 1 writes it's new value. Result: The buffer formerly held by thread 2 is leaked.

Comment: @Billy: Yes, I realized after I asked that, that atomic swap itself atomically reads both values.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb and say that you need a lock and that there is no general-case lock-free solution to this problem.

You would need to read from two addresses and write back to both addresses all atomically.  To the best of my knowledge, X86 can only atomically exchange data from a single memory address and a register.  I don't think it's possible to exchange the contents of two memory addresses.

If you can put constraints on where the pointers are, you can do this.  For example, if you can guarantee the pointers are adjacent in memory, you can use a 64- or 128-bit compare/exchange in a loop.

There may be solutions for other simple cases, but I don't think you're going to find a lock-free solution for the general case.

Comment: +1 -- looks like no `WindowsApi::AutoArray::Swap` thread safety for me. ('cause each pointer does NOT justify the overhead of maintaining a critical section!)

Comment: A limited selection of processors have a double compare-and-swap operation (DCAS / CAS2). You might also use CMPXCHG16B (double width) to similar effect. This is not "general" in that many CPUs do not support these instructions, but on ones that do it can be done. DCAS is on motorola 68k, CMPXCHG16B is on 64-bit Intel and *newer* 64-bit AMD, but not older ones. _InterlockedCompareExchange128 implements this as an array of 64-bit pointers evaluated as an atomic 128-bit field, but will explode if the processor does not support the instruction.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for an atomic, interlocked version of `swap`.

To my knowledge, there is no way to do this using only Windows API primitives and no explicit locking.  The various `Interlocked` functions being recommended by others will not work because only one of the passed-parameters is changed.  You want to change them both.

I might also point out that the `Interlocked` functions are only interlocked with respect to each other.  If you have another piece of code that updates one of these pointers but doesn't use `Interlocked`, your code is no longer safe.  I'm sure you realize this, but thought I'd mention it.

As far as I know, you'll need to use a library or write your own code to handle this.

Answer (score -2):

Check the x86 processor xchg instructions if they do what you want, then you can wrap them in inline assembly function. All processor single instructions are guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: This answer has the same problems as the InterlockedExchangePointer answers.

Comment: +1 because the *if* in *if they do what you want* returns false, therefore you're not going to find a simple way of doing this

Comment: @Pete: *If* that "if" returns false, then this doens't answer my question, even if it isn't factually incorrect.

Comment: @Billy: I agree.  @Gene basically said "I have no idea, but throw a dart at the manual and if it hits something you can use, then that is what you should use."  Its silly to +1 this answer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the statement "All processor single instructions are guaranteed to be atomic" is false.  It might be true, but on x86 I very sincerely doubt it.