# Hash table entry linked list - Mutex locks for thread safe operation

Tags: winapi, list, hash, mutex

Would a Win32 Mutex be the most efficient way to limit thread access to a linked list in a hash table? I didn't want to create a lot of handles, and the size of the hash table is variable. It could potentially be thousands. I didn't want to lock the whole list down when only one entry's list is being changed, so that would call for multiple Mutexes (one per each list), but I figured I could probably get away with pooling about 20 Mutex handles and reusing them since there shouldn't be that many threads accessing it simultaneously. Is there an alternative to Mutex locks for this case?

Comment: if thread are all in the same process i'd use criticalsections not mutexes

Comment: So InitializeCriticalSection(), EnterCriticalSection(), LeaveCriticalSection() API calls in Win32?

Comment: Yep, operate far simpler than mutexes, but only work within a single process

Comment: +1 on Critical sections. Also, comment on the original qu; I'm curious about the pooling approach: seems this would require keeping track of which list (if any) each lock in the pool is associated with, requiring another data structure, which itself would then need a lock... :)

Comment: But having a hash table with 1033 entries or maybe more with a lock on each would require 24792 bytes total (24 bytes per CRITICAL_SECTION structure). That's why I could create a pool (with a single lock) with about 20 nodes (20 x 24 = 480 bytes). It's a tradeoff of memory over speed I guess. There shouldn't be that many threads going so I think it would be less of a hit even if the pool has a lock.

Answer (score 0):

A lot here depends on the details of your hash table. My immediate reaction would be to avoid a mutex/critical section at all, at least if you can.

At least for adding an item to the linked list, it's pretty easy to avoid it by using an [`InterlockedExchangePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683609.aspx) instead. Presumably you have a struct something like:

```
struct LL_item { 
    LL_item *next;
    std::string key;
    whatever_type value;
};
```

To insert an item of this type into a linked list, you do something like:

```
LL_item *item = new LL_item;

// set key and value here
item->next = &item;
InterlockedExchangePointer(&item->next, &bucket->head);
```

Prior to the `InterlockedExchangePointer`, `bucket->head` contains the address of the first item currently in the list. We initialize our new item with its own address in its `next` pointer. We then (atomically) exchange the next pointer in our new item with the pointer to the pointer to the (previous) first node in the list. After the exchange, the new node's next pointer contains the address of the previously-first item in the list, and the pointer to the head of the list contains the address of our new node.

I believe you can (probably) normally use an exchange to remove an item from a list as well, but I'm not sure -- I haven't thought through that quite as thoroughly. Quite a few hash tables don't (even try to) support deletion anyway, so you may not care about that though.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to use `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683568.aspx

Comment: @JimMischel: Do you mean to remove an item from the list? In that case, yes, probably. If you're talking about inserting into the list, I'm not sure what you gain from the comparison.

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding something. My read of the `InterlockedExchangePointer` doc says that the value at `&item->next` would change, but the value at `&bucket->head` would not. My suggestion to use `InterlockedCompareExchangePointer` wouldn't fix that. The accepted answer to a similar question indicates that there is no atomic swap of two memory locations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503628/how-can-i-atomically-swap-two-pointers-on-windows

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a [slim reader writer lock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa904937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Sure, it locks the entire data structure when you're doing updates, but typically you'll have a lot more reads than writes to the hash table. My experience with SRW locks is that it works quite well and performance is very good. You probably should give it a try. That'll get your program working. Then you can profile the code to determine if there are bottlenecks and if so where the bottlenecks are. It's quite possible that the SRW lock is plenty fast enough.